# jquery and json response data

Tags: jquery, json, asp-classic, voting

i try to get the json output after voting but i couldn't get the success message after voting. what kind of a json output i need to write in the voting page. pls help me. i don't know jquery even json but i adapted this to my site everything is ok. vote is recorded database successfully but for the last step i must write the updated new vote values but i coludn't. when i use an error message it alert it but in success it isn't working. my page is in asp language. help pls.

```
(function($){
$(function(){
var g='http://my_own_computer.net/';
var h=$('form.thumbsup');
h.submit(function(){return false});
h.find(':input').click(function(){var a=$(this);a.closest('form').trigger('thumsup_vote',[a.val()])});h.bind('thumsup_vote',

function(c,d){
    var e=$(this),
    template=e.attr('name');
    if(e.hasClass('busy')||e.hasClass('disabled'))return;
    e.addClass('busy');
    var f={small:'<img class="spinner" alt="···" src="'+g+'images/spinner_small.gif" />',large:'<img class="spinner" alt="···" src="'+g+'images/spinner_large.gif" />',large_green:'<img class="spinner" alt="···" src="'+g+'images/spinner_large_green.gif" />',large_red:'<img class="spinner" alt="···" src="'+g+'images/spinner_large_red.gif" />'};

switch(template){
case'buttons':e.find('.question, :button').remove();e.find('.result1').after(' '+f.small);break;
case'mini_poll':e.find('.result1, .result2').html(f.small);break;
case'mini_thumbs':e.find('.result1').html(f.small);break;
case'thumbs_up_down':e.find('.result2').html(f.large_red);
case'thumbs_up':e.find('.result1').html(f.large_green);break;
case'up_down':e.find('.result1').html(f.large);break}

$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url:g+'edit.asp?part=qvote',
cache:false,
dataType:'json',
timeout:15000,
data:{thumbsup_id:e.find('input[name=thumbsup_id]').val(),thumbsup_format:e.find('input[name=thumbsup_format]').val(),thumbsup_vote:d},

error:function(a,b){e.find('.error').text(b)},

success:function(a){if('error'in a){switch(a.error){
case'invalid_id':
e.css('visibility','hidden');
alert('The item you voted on no longer exists.');
break;

case'closed':
e.addClass('closed disabled');
alert('Voting has been closed for this item.');
break;

case'already_voted':
case'ip_blocked':
e.addClass('user_voted disabled');
alert('You have already voted on this item.');
break;

case'login_required':
alert('Oy verebilmek için üyemiz olmalısınız.');
break;
default:alert(a.error)
}

//vote saved but new values coming from the page via json arent being able to print to the page 
return}
// The user has voted
e.addClass('user_voted disabled');

for(var i=0;i<a.item.result.length;i++){e.find('.result'+(i+1)).text(a.item.result[i]).fadeTo(0,0.01).fadeTo('slow',1)}

if(template==='mini_poll'){e.find('.graph').css({opacity:0,width:0}).show().filter('.up').animate({opacity:1,width:a.item.votes_pct_up+'%'}).end().filter('.down').animate({opacity:1,width:a.item.votes_pct_down+'%'})}},

complete:function(){e.find('.spinner').remove();e.removeClass('busy')

}})});

$(window).load(function(){if(h.filter('.thumbs_up').length){var a=new Image;a.src=g+'images/spinner_small.gif';var a=new Image;a.src=g+'images/spinner_large.gif';var a=new Image;a.src=g+'images/spinner_large_green.gif';var a=new Image;a.src=g+'images/spinner_large_red.gif'}})})})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the vote is saved in the database, to have the vote show (or success message) on the active page, you need to select the element you would like to update, and then render its html with jquery.

This code will go in the success section of your ajax code.

For example (updating a vote counter)

```
var vote_element       = $('#the_ele_with_the_count');
var current_vote_count = Number(vote_element.text());
//convert string to # to add/sub properly

var new_count = current_vote_count+1;

//update in DOM
vote_element.text(new_count);
```